# h2o deeplearning vs other packages(tensorflow, theano etc)

Tags: h2o

How does h2o implementation of deep learning differs from tensorflow or theano. [This tutorial](https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/blob/master/py/examples/notebooks/TensorFlowDeepLearning.ipynb) shows the tensorflow implementation in h2o.

And what is the use of tensorflow in h2o, when h2o itself can find minimum for the NN's gradient descent problem.

Answer (score 0):

h2o's deeplearning functionality is is missing features that are present in the tensorflow implementation. For example, h2o's deeplearning function does not currently support constitutional neural networks.

See the first slide in the presentation here: https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater/blob/master/README.md